# Change background color closest class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following HTML:

```
<article>
    <a href="#" title="Title">
        <span class="row first">
            <span class="col">
                <span class="articleTitle">Article title</span>
                <span class="row">
                    <span class="tel">12345</span>
                    <span class="mail">test@domain.com</span>               
                </span>                     
            </span>
            <span>
                <span class="articleFlag flagNone"></span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</article>
<article>
    <a href="#" title="Title">
        <span class="row first">
            <span class="col">
                <span class="articleTitle">Article title</span>
                <span class="row">
                    <span class="tel">12345</span>
                    <span class="mail">test@domain.com</span>               
                </span>                     
            </span>
            <span>
                <span class="articleFlag flagRed"></span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
</article>
```

And now I would like to change the background-color from the span with class 'articleTitle' to red, if the class 'flagNone' is set in this article. It should only change in this article not in the following one.

I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.articleFlag.flagNone')) {
        $('.articleFlag.flagNone').closest('.articleTitle').css("background", "red");
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: `.closest()` checks each parent traveling up the DOM tree, but `.articleTitle` isn't a parent.

Comment: Is this HTML being generated, or is this a static DOM you're working with, because if it's generated, you could setup your HTML to work with this a lot better...

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please check this [Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sphd30fu/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.articleFlag.flagNone').length>0) {
        $('.articleFlag.flagNone').closest('.row').find('.articleTitle').css("background-color", "red");
    }
});
```

I think it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `:has()` selector ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w0t5LwmL/1/))

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.articleFlag.flagNone')) {
        $('.row:has(.flagNone) .articleTitle').css("background", "red");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Closest traverse up the dom tree, that  is the reason your selector doesn't work

try below js code

```
  if ($('.articleFlag.flagNone')) {
     $('.articleFlag.flagNone').parents('.row:eq(0)').find('.articleTitle').css("background", "red");
      }
```